# How to handle "Please open the following address in your browser " on CI for Gmail Api

Tags: java, gmail-api

My Java automation test require to receive email, so I decided to use Gmail API. I went over this official guide https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java and locally it works well for me, but in case of CI (Gitlab) execution I stuck at the step :
" Please open the following address in your browser: ... "

[image]

Looks like the problem is because on CI chrome is in headless mode, so how to open url in headless mode?

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: Provided the details, official gmail api  page explain what is expected.

Comment: The code you are using is designed for an installed application.  Its going to require that you authorize it.  To do that you have to open the consent screen in a browser.  It cant open it for you.

Comment: @DaImTo , but how can I open it on CI, can you provide example?

Comment: @ВладиславЗагородний you don't.  To get access to a users gmail account you need the permission of that user.  The user cant grant you that permission from CI.   You need to be running this on a website where the user can grant you access.   If you are Doing tests then you should be using mocks not live end to end testing to Gmail.   That said we may have different opinions on how testing is preformed.